# Django POST dict empty, use simple html form

Tags: python, django, http

I am use Django 1.8 and Python 3.5.2, and try recive POST data from simple html form

```
<form action="/shop/order" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="product-code" value="{{ product.product_code }}">
        <input type="text" name="email">
        <input type="submit">
</form>
```

It view where I try get need for me data, but QueryDict empty for POST, **when I change POST to GET in form and view all work.**

```
def order_product(request):
    test = request.POST.get('product-code', '')
    mail = request.POST.get('email', '')
    # logger.info(test)
    return render(request, 'shop/test.html', dict(test=test, email=mail))
```

And I'am not understand why is that. Similarly I try parse(decode binary to utf-8 etc) body and I recive empty string.

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^order/?$', views.order_product),
```

Comment: Hahaha, I change form action to `/ru/shop/order` and it work, I forgot l18n....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all, the moral of this fable is as follows, use name argument in urls, and use {% url 'name' %} in template. I have i18n in urls(from djangoCMS) and when I harcode url in form isn't work for POST method.